# Is it possible in SSMS to pull a DATETIME value as DATE?

Tags: sql, ssms

I want to start by saying my SQL knowledge is limited (the sololearn SQL basics course is it), and I have fallen into a position where I am regularly asked to pull data from the SQL database for our ERP software. I have been pretty successful so far, but my current problem is stumping me.

I need to filter my results by having the date match from 2 separate tables.

My issue is that one of the tables outputs DATETIME with full time data. e.g. "2022-08-18 11:13:09.000"

While the other table zeros the time data. e.g. "2022-08-18 00:00:00.000"

Is there a way I can on the fly convert these to just a DATE e.g. "2022-08-18" so I can set them equal and get the results I need?

Comment: You have not provided any details of the tables, the column data types or your query. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple CAST statement should work if I understand correctly.

```
CAST( dateToConvert AS DATE)
```

Comment: Where would I put that in the code? My current inner join shows the following 

"dbo.Job_Operation.Actual_Start = dbo.PO_Header.Order_Date"

Comment: This site, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sql-cast-and-convert-statement/ , shows some good examples, they are usually in the SELECT or WHERE clause. If the answer is useful upvote it please and good luck!